# Spring4 Aop on Spring mvc controller error

Tags: spring-mvc, aop, aspectj

code:

```
@Aspect
@Order(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
public class KeySortedAspect {

    @Pointcut(value = "@annotation(com.le.bigdata.convertor.KeySortedRule)")
    public void pointCut(){}

    @Around(value = "pointCut()")
    public Object keySorted(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) signature;
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        if(methodSignature.getMethod().isAnnotationPresent(KeySortedRule.class)){
            KeySortedRule keySortedRule = methodSignature.getMethod().getAnnotation(KeySortedRule.class);
            String path = keySortedRule.path();
        //String rule = keySortedRule.rule();
        try {
            Map<String, String[]> keyMap = getRule(path);
            Class<?> type = methodSignature.getMethod().getReturnType();
            Object a = sortedUseKeyList(result, keyMap, type);
            return a;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Key sorted Error");
            logger.error("reason ", e);
        }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

spring mvc configuration mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<!-- controller层 内部ctrl与lebi对接的ctrl -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.le.bigdata.controller, com.le.bigdata.api.controller"/>

<bean id="keySortedAspect" class="com.le.bigdata.convertor.KeySortedAspect"/>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("cp")
public class ContentPortraitController {
    @Autowired
    private IContentPortraitService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "usertop", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ApiOperation(value = "获取默认的cv排名前10名的专辑")
    private CommonResponseDTO getUserTop(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int size){
        List<Map<String, Object>> list = service.getDefaultPid(size);
        return new CommonResponseDTO(true, list);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/album", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ApiOperation(value = "获取专辑画像", httpMethod = "GET")
    @KeySortedRule(path="content_portrait")
    public JSONObject getAlbum(@RequestParam(value="dt",required = false) String dt,
                           @RequestParam(value="start_dt",required = false) String start,
                           @RequestParam(value="end_dt",required = false) String end,
                           @RequestParam(value="product",required = false) List<String> product,
                           @RequestParam(value="pid") String pid){

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject data = null;
        try {
            if(dt != null && !dt.isEmpty()){
            //
                data = service.getAlbumPortrait(pid, dt, product);
            } else if(start != null && end != null && !start.isEmpty() && !end.isEmpty()){
            //
                data = service.getAlbumPortrait(pid, start, end, product);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        result.put("result", data);
        return result;
}
}
```

When I request /cp/album it works and response data.
But I request /cp/usertop it throw an exception: NullPointException 
reference service is null!  service could not be null, IContentPortraitService is an interface and has only one implementation. And I absolutely sure I have scan service package and use @Service annotation on it's implementation.

Debug information:

When I request /cp/usertop:

ContentProtrationController instance is ContentPortraitServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySprinigCGLIB$bdfd5678@7591 and service is null

When I request /cp/album:

ContentProtrationController instance is ContentPortraitServiceImpl@7591 and service is not null, it works.

What's wrong with my code? This problem has troubled me for many days.Who knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: I am not a Spring user, I just stumbled upon this question because of AspectJ. BTW, your aspect iq quite complicated and uses more reflection than necessary. But maybe the problem is unrelated to the aspect as such. Could it be that you need to write `value = "/usertop"` with a slash as the first value character similar to `value = "/album"`?

Comment: @kriegaex thank u for your answer, value = "/usertop" equals value="usertop" in spring. It not essential if the first value character is a slash.

Comment: I have found how resolve this problem. The method getAlbum modifier is public but other method getUserTop is private.It works if I change method getUserTop modifier to public.Why?

Comment: Oh right, I did not notice. And because I use full-blown AspectJ and not proxy-based Spring AOP I sometimes forget about that restriction in Spring AOP. The reason is that Spring AOP uses dynamic proxies (JDK type for interfaces, CGLIB type for classes) and thus is restricted to public methods. This is documented in the Spring manual. So either you make your mekds public if they are to be targeted by Spring AOP or you use full AspectJ, which is also possible from within Spring.